# Non blocking socket in c

Tags: c, sockets, udp

Currently I am working on a single server,single client udp chat application. Initially I used blocking sockets which is the default condition. Now I want to convert the socket into non-blocking so that communication between client and server could be done without the obstacle of turns...
I've implemented the select function on the server side for now,but the when it starts the client gets to send a message once which is displayed on the server side,afterwards both client and server get unresponsive, so now I am showing how have I implemented the select() function on the server side:

```
            //Declaring a non-blocking structure
              fd_set readfds,writefds;
           // clear the set ahead of time
              FD_ZERO(&readfds);
              FD_ZERO(&writefds);
           // add our descriptor to the set
              FD_SET(sd, &readfds);
              FD_SET(sd, &writefds);
              /value of sd+1
              int n=sd+1;
```

Since I want to both receive and send data,I've implemented the select function in the loop:

```
                int client_length = (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
                int rv = select(n, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                if(rv==-1)
                {
                 printf("Error in Select!!!\n");
                 exit(0);
                }
               else if(rv==0)
                { 
                 printf("Timeout occurred\n");
                }
               else 
                if (FD_ISSET(sd, &readfds))
                {
                int bytes_received = recvfrom(sd, buffer,SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_length);
                if (bytes_received < 0)
               {
               fprintf(stderr, "Could not receive datagram.\n");
               closesocket(sd);
               WSACleanup();
               exit(0);
              }
                }
```

further for sending data:

```
              fgets(buffer,SIZE,stdin);
              int rv1 = select(n, &writefds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
              if(rv1==-1)
              {
           printf("Error in Select!!!\n");
           exit(0);
              }
             else if(rv1==0)
             {
            printf("Timeout occurred\n");
             }
            else 
             if(FD_ISSET(sd,&writefds))
                  {
                     if(sendto(sd, buffer,strlen(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client,client_length)<0)
                         {
                            printf("Error sending the file! \n");
                            exit(1);
                         }
                  }

                }
```

So I would really appreciate if somoone let me know whether I've done this right or not,if this is ok then will the same implelementation on the client side resolve my issue?

Comment: Remember that `select()` overwrites its inputs so you have to recreate the `fd_set`s each time you call the function (or make copies of them).  I'm not sure if that's your problem, but it is a common problem with `select()` code.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler: so should I initialize the "readfds" & "writefds" in the loop?

Comment: Yes - you need to initialize `readfds` and `writefds` in the loop because `select()` modifies them when you call it.

Comment: ok I've implemented the same thing on the client side as well but it's still working as a blocking application:(

Comment: please let me know where am I going worng or if it's the right approcah or not...I saw the example of select() and it basically handled two sockets to check whehter they ahd incoming data or not...

Comment: At this stage, it is difficult to know what resemblances there are between your current code and the code in the question, which in turn makes it hard to help much more.  One possibility is that you alter the question to add your current code to it (leaving the original code largely intact so that the answer is not invalidated).  Another possibility is to 'accept' the answer for this question and to open a new one.  I don't have strong views on which is better.

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
select(n, &writefds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

The second argument is used to check for readability only. To check for writability, use the third argument:

```
select(n, NULL, &writefds, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Now I have one question,if I implement same thing on the client side,shall I be able to create a non-blocking udp chat application,coz so far I've done this on the server side but I still get the feel of blocking socket...

Comment: @AaymanKhalid you have to implement it on both sides, of course :)

Comment: @ robertkelp,I've but it's still working as a blocking application,the clientand server still communicate one by one and if I try to send data from one side more than once it get's displayed next time:(

Comment: @AaymanKhalid I think you're going to need to combine both `select` statements into one: `select(n, &readfds, &writefds, NULL, NULL)`

Comment: @ robertklep,If I do as you said,the server prints a an entire array of redundant data when it starts without the client even connecting!!!